# If $G=AB$ is a factorization st $q\not\mid |A|$ where $q$ is prime, then for $g\in G,a\in A$, there is a unique $x_1\in A$ st $\alpha(gx_1^q)=a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $A,B$ be subsets of $G$.
> Suppose $AB$ is a factorization of $G$, that is, every $g\in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $ab$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Here $a$ is called the $A$-part of $g$ and denoted by $\alpha(g)$.
> Let $q$ be a prime such that $q\not\mid |A|$.

Choose an $a\in A,g\in G$ and define $T$ to be the set of all $q$ tuples $$(x_1,\dots,x_q) \text{ where } x_1,\dots,x_q\in A$$
for which $$\alpha(gx_1\dots x_q)=a.$$
By using the fact that $|T|=|A|^{q-1}$ and group action (cyclic permutation), it can be shown that there is an $x_1\in A$ such that $\alpha(gx_1^q)=a$. What I want to show here is that $x_1$ is uniquely determined by $a$ and $g$.

Let $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $\alpha(gx_1^q)=a=\alpha(gx_2^q)$. I want to show that $x_1=x_2$. There exist $b_1,b_2\in B$ such that $gx_1^q=ab_1$ and $gx_2^q=ab_2$. Then I get $(x_1x_2^{-1})^q=b_1b_2^{-1}$. I need some idea or hint to complete the proof.

Comment: Hint:  Try showing that $\alpha(g x_1^q) = \alpha(g) x_1^q$, and similarly for $x_2^q$.  Afterwards, can you show that $x_1^q = x_2^q$ implies $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: @RaviFernando I still can't get your hint.

Comment: Are you claiming that $|A|$ is finite and that the map $A\to A$ sending $x_1\mapsto \alpha(gx_1^q)$ is surjective and asking if it is also injective?  If so does the pigeonhole principle not suffice?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I thought $A$ and $B$ were subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in my comment, if $A$ is finite then the pigeonhole principle together with your elegant proof (+1) that the map $A\to A$ sending $x\mapsto \alpha(gx^q)$ is surjective, implies that it is also injective.

On the other hand if $A$ is infinite we have the following counterexample:

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $$A=\{6n,6n+1,6n+2| n\in \mathbb{Z}\},\qquad B=\{0,3\}$$
Let $q=3$ (I am ignoring the condition $q\not\!||A|$ when $A$ infinite, as it is not clear what it means).

Then the map $x\mapsto \alpha(0+3x)$ is neither injective nor surjective:\begin{eqnarray}0&\mapsto&0,\\1&\mapsto&0,\end{eqnarray}
and $3x\neq1,4 \implies \alpha(0+3x)\neq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually $G$ is assumed to be finite but anyway thanks for giving counterexample when $G$ is infinite.